# $L^p$ integrable local martingale is still $L^p$ integrable when stopped at localizing stopping times.

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, stopping-times

Assume that $X$ is $L^p$ integrable  for $1\leq p\leq \infty$ (i.e., for all $t$, $X_t\in L^p$) and is also a (Cadlag) local martingale. If $T_n$ is a localizing sequence of stopping times for $X$. Is it true that the stopped process $X^{T_n}$ remains $L^p$ integrable?

The answer is clearly yes for the discrete time case and also in the continuous case for the cases $p=1,p=\infty$. So I'm guessing it should be yes in general but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Do you assume, e.g. $T_n \leq n$ for each $n$? If not, I don't see how the discrete case is clear.

Comment: Nevermind, I see now, I was thinking you were asking if $X_{T_n}$ is integrable.

Answer (score 0):

Well I am not sure this is true. I give you an argument to be discussed about which I'm not totally comfortable.

Let's fix $T_n=T$, let's suppose it has a law $P_T(ds)$ and that $T$ is independent of $(M_t)_{t>0}$ and finally that $M_t$ positive for all $t>0$.

Now for any $t>0$ we have a fixed $p\in (1,\infty)$ such that $M_t\in L^p$, and we have :

$$E[(M^T_t)^p]=E[(M_t.1[T>t]+M_T.1[T\leq t])^p]\geq  E[(M_T.1[T\leq t])^p]= E[M_T^p.1[T\leq t]]$$

Now using the law of $T$ :

$$E[M_T^p.1[T\leq t]]=E[\int_0^t M_s^pdP_T(ds)]$$

and independence :

$$E[M_T^p.1[T\leq t]]=\int_0^t E[M_s^p]dP_T(ds)$$

Noting $g_{(p,M)}(s)=E[M_s^p]$, we see that if $g_{(p,M)}(s).1[0,t](s)$ is not in $L^1(P_T(ds),\mathbb{R}^+)$ the process is not $L^p$-integrable in t.

The truth is that I am not fully sure about this and especially about the fact that such conditions can be met in practice.

Best regards

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply. I don't think the argument is valid though. If $M$ is positive and a local martingale then it will be a positive submartingale and so will be $M^p$ by Jensen. In that case $(M^T)^p=(M^p)^T$ which is an integrable submartingale. In particular we get that $M^T$ is $p$ integrable. Although I don't have a proof in hand, I think the localizing sequence of stopping times will hardly be independent of the local martingale they localize. This is clear for the most frequently used $T_n=inf\{t>= 0:M_t>=n\}$. Best regards

Comment: @ webbster : Well unless mistaken a positive local martingale is a super-martingale not a sub-martingale (look at lemma 2 : https://almostsure.wordpress.com/2009/12/24/local-martingales/#scn_locmart_lem2). In the end I agree with you that my argument seems fishy. Best regards.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Thank you for the correction. Best regards